# Xcode AppIcon based on scheme

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm aware that you can change the AppIcon based on build targets, so some people create dev, staging, release build targets with different AppIcons like this article suggests: 
[Different App Icons for your iOS Beta, Dev, and Release builds](https://engineering.circle.com/different-app-icons-for-your-ios-beta-dev-and-release-builds-af4d209cdbfd)

However I would like to do this by schemes if possible.

I have 4 build targets:

- Dev
- QA
- Staging
- Release

And many schemes, which using react-native-config I can build different flavors based on environment variables:

- Public
- Public Premium
- B2B
- B2B Premium

Using schemes I can have many versions of the app at once on a device using the BundleID which gets changed using react-native-config.

How can I use schemes to differ the AppIcon?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you're already using 'Environment Variables' to modify things like Bundle Identifier, you could totally do the same for AppIcons.

I don't know a lot about React Native configuration but in Xcode you can edit Target's build settings easily. For demonstration purpose I've create a test project and added a 'Premium' Configuration.

For instance if I would like to change the Bundle Identifier on my test project. I need to go under **Target > Build Settings** and search For **'Product Bundle Identifier'** here I can set a different bundle id for each config.

[image: Screenshot 1]

The exact same mechanic apply for App Icons. To find the setting I must go under **Target > Build Settings** once again and search for **'Assets Catalog Compiler - Options'** under this one I look for another options called **'Asset Catalog App Icon Set Name'** and here you can chose a different Icon for any configuration. Here I chose AppIcon-Premium for my Premium config

[image: Screenshot 2]

Of course you need to create another IOS App Icon

[image: Screenshot 3]

[image: Screenshot 4]

I am conscious that for this example I am using Configuration over Schemes, but for me a Scheme is just a quick way to switch between configurations.

Here is a StackOverflow thread about Schemes and Configurations differences: [understanding Xcode schemes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606057/understanding-xcode-schemes)

I hope this answer could help you at least a bit. I recently spent so much time struggling to understand Xcode mechanics... However I am still a Newbie and I am probably missing a lot of things. Even if you're still stuck I hope that my answer could help you to improve your search !

I wish you best of luck !

Comment: the answer is a good one for changing values based on Build Configuration - but the question is about changing based on Scheme, not Build Configuration

Comment: @HK for the Scheme you can leverage of User-Defined Settings for your single Target. Take a look at https://engineering.circle.com/different-app-icons-for-your-ios-beta-dev-and-release-builds-af4d209cdbfd for full instructions.

Comment: @HK You can define different configuration to use for each scheme. Scheme->Edit->RUN->Build configuration : choose Release\Debug\<whatever you want>